# dpkg error while running apt-get autoclean

Tags: apt, dpkg, cleanup

I was installing android studio through the terminal but I had to stop the installation by pressing Ctrl+Z. Now I am trying to run autoclean (after a restart) but it won't run.Why is this happening?

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 
'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

EDIT:
autoclean worked after i ran dpkg --configure -a.
But, it still has not removed the inconsistent/incomplete android-studio package.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error messages you see when running `dpkg --configure -a`. That is the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling it with Synaptic Package Manager.

Go to the synaptic. Type in the search bar : 'android'.

Mark it for complete removal and apply.